# Cannot load HTML in a div that was ajax'd in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Good afternoon, I am at a total loss on why this is happening.  I have searched online and tried to understand what I'm doing wrong for 5+ hours and could find no solution.  Here is the situation.

I have 3 pages (index.html, index.js, and stuff.html)
index.html is the main page and uses jQuery to load an HTML page into a div.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="stuffHolder"></div>
  <script type="text.javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#stuffHolder').load('stuff.html');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The stuff.html page loads just fine for me.

Inside the stuff.html I have 2 div's
1. One of the DIV's uses sprites as anchor tags to call a function named actOnStuff(options).

```
<div id="myStuff"><a class="myStuffSprite" href="Javascript:actOnStuff('newStuff')"><span>New Stuff</span></a></div>
<div id="yourStuff"><a class="yourStuffSprite" href="Javascript:actOnStuff('oldStuff')"><span>Old Stuff</span></a></div>
```

1. The other DIV is empty but will have innerHTML written to it later.

Inside index.js, which sits on the index.html page, I have a function

```
function actOnStuff(youSelected){
  strHTML = "";
  switch(youSelected){
    case "newStuff":
      strHTML += "<div id='newDIV'><span>You selected New</span></div>";
      break;
    case "oldStuff":
      strHTML += "<div id='oldDIV'><span>You selected Old</span></div>";
      break;
  }
  $('#placement').html(strHTML);
  alert($('#placement').html());
}
```

My problem is that when I alert the innerHTML of the placement DIV it shows that the necessary DIV from the function as added in the alert.  HOWEVER, nothing shows up in the placement DIV at all.

Any help you can provide would be wonderful as I am at a total loss as to what the problem is.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the `placement` element? Please, create a test case at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You should create a http://jsfiddle.net for others to see the problem. You often find the problem yourself when creating reductions. As it stands, it doesn't look like anything is wrong with what you've shown us.

Comment: I hope you don't have a `display:none` css rule set for `#placement`, which reminds me you haven't disclosed anything about CSS so far

Comment: I've never used jFiddle before and the bad part is it's for work and I can't bring that home.  The css for placement is position:absolute; top: 0px; left:30px; width: 300px; height: 300px; that is all for placement.  The two DIV's in the javascript function only display sprites.  The only thing set to display none is the span.  The DIV's themselves are display: inline-block; height: 10px; width: 10px; background: url('imageX.jpg') no-repeat -100px -300px;  I can try to figure out jFiddle to produce an example.

Comment: Ok I need help with jFiddle.  How can I display 3 pages with it?  Can someone lend me a hand please?

Comment: ok not sure if I got this right but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/9nqHr/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I can help solve the actual problem, but there's many issues and bad practices in your code that I'd like to point out for the greater good of the community.

Here's my take on your code:

**HTML in body**

```
<div id="stuff-holder"></div>
```

**HTML in stuff.html**

```
<div id="my-stuff">
    <a class="my-stuff-sprite" href="#"><span>New Stuff</span></a>
</div>
<div id="your-stuff">
    <a class="your-stuff-sprite" href="#"><span>Old Stuff</span></a>
</div>
```

*Bad practice: CSS and HTML is most of the time not case-sensitive, so when naming IDs with camelcase such as `fooBar`, could create confusion with `foobar` or `Foobar`. Instead, use lowercase only and dash as separator (like in CSS).*

**JavaScript in index.js**

I moved your `ready` function into `index.js`. I don't see a reason why you would want that in your HTML document when you already have a separate JavaScript file.

```
// Shorthand for ready
$(function(){

    // Cache the selector
    var $placement = $("#placement");

    // Put function in the local scope so we don't clutter the global scope
    function actOnStuff(youSelected) {
        // Not declaring variables with var, makes it global (bad idea!)
        var html = "";

        switch (youSelected) {
            case "my-stuff":
                html += '<div id="new-div"><span>You selected New</span></div>';
            break;

            case "your-stuff":
                html += '<div id="old-div"><span>You selected Old</span></div>';
            break;
        }

        // Put new html in placement element
        $placement.html(html);

        // Use console.log to debug your code instead of alert
        console.log($placement.html());
    }

    // Load stuff into stuff holder and bind event handler to load event
    $("#stuff-holder")
        .load("stuff.html")
        .on("load", function() {
            // After it has loaded, bind click events
            $("#my-stuff .my-stuff-sprite, #your-stuff .your-stuff-sprite").click(function(e) {
                // Prevent default click behavior
                e.preventDefault();
                // Get id of parent
                var id = $(this).parent()[0].id;
                // Execute function
                actOnStuff(id);
            });
        });
});
```

*Bad practice: Executing JavaScript within the `href` is a big no-no in todays environments. Even using `onclick` attributes et al is since long outdated.*

*Tip: Passing a function directly into jQuery is a shorthand for `$(document).ready`*

*Tip: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` to output everything from objects to strings to your log (might give you errors in older IE)*

I still don't know where your `placement` element is located. Perhaps that's your culprit? If you have any questions about the above or anything else, don't hesitate to ask.

Also, check out [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com) which is a great resource for everyone using jQuery, from beginners to pros.

**Edit:** Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/9nqHr/5/) for a demonstration of the above.

Comment: Thanks for the intel.  The placement DIV for jFiddle I placed in the HTML at the bottom.  That is where the case string, in your code "html" is going to be placed.  Good to know that javascript in href is a big no no.  I'll augment that code.  However, if you add the DIV with id placement in I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Here is more of a breakdown of why I'm doing what I'm doing.  I have a page, index.html that uses ajax to load multiple HTML pages.  Think of it this way, each DIV is a module that does something different and does not interact with each other.  So the index.html is a canvas with, let's say 5 DIV's.  Each DIV load something different.  All of them I got to load properly.  Except this one.  When I load "stuff.html" into the stuff-holder DIV the page stuff.html does load properly.

Comment: Within stuff.html are two DIV's one named "my-stuff" and the other "your-stuff".  In the my-stuff DIV are the sprites or anchors that have the links that call the actOnStuff function.  When the user selects a link the switch case then builds a string and loads that string into the your-stuff DIV depending on what you selected.  But that is not happening.  The "html" string does not appear in the your-stuff DIV.  However, if you alert the innerHTML of the your-stuff DIV the html displays in the alert.  Why is it showing up in the alert and not visible on the page?

Comment: Just realized that the cases in the switch-statement contained the wrong IDs (should be `my-stuff` and `your-stuff`, not `new-stuff` and `old-stuff`). I've updated the example and also added a link to a working fiddle. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot tomorrow at work and let you know if it worked or not.  I really appreciate all your help.  I'll update tomorrow evening on my findings since we cannot log into stackoverflow at work.

Comment: Good morning, I tried to use your same method in jsFiddle and keep getting an _display error.  here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8A2hY/

Comment: I found my error.  First you were correct that I needed to bind my click events.  However, I still wa snot getting any results.  Then I noticed I my not be in "scope" for the actions to work.  So when the html page was ajax'd in I placed the div DOM object into a varaible and finally I was able to interact with it and everything works now.  Thank you soooo much for your help it was great.

Answer (score 1):

before

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

you should load `jquery` library first

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: If jquery wasn't loaded would the code not start crashing at the first us of `$(document).ready...` with `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`?

Comment: The page loads fine and jquery does come before index.js.  Apologies for not indicating that in my example

Comment: The kicker is adding innerHTML to a page that was ajax'd in using javascript.  I say that because I was able to change the background-color on the stuffHolder DIV within the actOnStuff function so I know it's picking up the event but the div's from the function will not appear in the placement DIV even though if I do an alert the innerHTML shows that they are in there.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you only have ONE element with id="placement", IE will fail if you have more than one.
- Also what is the output of `alert(strHTML);` putted just before `$('#placement').html(strHTML);` does it output the string right?

Comment: the DIV placement is the only DIV with that name.  The alert output for strHTML is the correct DIV from the switch case.